# Matching values from different scopes in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am attempting to apply a class to elements depending on their 'category' property, while interacting with a dynamic list of categories the user can also create.

Categories array:

```
$scope.categories = [{
    category: "work",
    id: 1
  }, {
    category: "life",
    id: 2
  ];
```

Todos array:

```
$scope.todos = [{
        name: "Lift Up Hats",
        category: "life",
        date: "tomorrow"
    }, {
        name: "Wash the Horse",
        category: "work",
        date: "tomorrow"
    }];
```

What I am effectively looking to do is:

A) Loop everything in the todos array. So far doing that this way:

```
<li class="{{todo.category}}-item" ng-repeat="todo in todos | orderBy: 'completed'">
```

However, that depends on classes being called things like "life-item",  "work-item" etc. I want to use the IDs in the categories array.

B) If 'lift up hats' has a category of 'life', assign it the ID of the category life, from the categories array. For example, life would result in "1-item" , work would result in "2-item" etc.

I have looked into using the .map function for this, but it seems I would then have to restructure the way the array is manipulated across the whole application.

Some assistance/advice would be much appreciated.

TL;DR:
I’m trying to apply a class to an ng-repeated item looping from one array, where the class is a property in another array where the properties match on both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a filter to provide a lookup

NB: I stole the filter "fromNative" somewhere I dont remenber so sorry to dont provide the credits for that

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  
  $scope.categories = [{
    category: "work",
    id: 1
    }, {
    category: "life",
    id: 2
    }
  ];
  
  $scope.todos = [{
    name: "Lift Up Hats",
    category: "life",
    date: "tomorrow"
  }, {
    name: "Wash the Horse",
    category: "work",
    date: "tomorrow"
  }];
});

app.filter('fromNative', function () {
    return function (native, options, matchField, valueField) {
        if (options) {
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                var o = options[i][matchField];
                if (o === native) {
                    return options[i][valueField];
                }
            }
        }
        return '';
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <li ng-repeat="todo in todos | orderBy: 'completed'">
    with {{todo.name}} my lookup is <b>{{ todo.category | fromNative : categories : 'category' :'id' }}</b>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**
I had replace my todos to match your sample

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks. I'll have to go back and figure out how it works though, serious gap in my knowledge when it comes to filters.

Answer (score 0):

Following jQuery code can help you:

```
angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(i, todoOb){
    angular.forEach($scope.categories, function(cat_i, catOb){
        if(todoOb.category == catOb.category){
            todoOb.id = catOb.id;
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<li class="{{todo.id}}-item" ng-repeat="todo in todos | orderBy: 'completed'">
```

This will add the right keys from categories to todos array object elements.

Comment: Appreciate the answer! Not sure if I want to load another library to the project for one function but I will look into a vanilla JS implementation of this. :) Thanks!

Comment: I assumed that you are using `jquery` in conjuction with angular. The same I have done can too be done in Javascript as well.

Comment: AngularJS has its only jQueryLite library you can use with a .forEach function: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Comment: Or as both are arrays, just use the native `forEach`. `$scope.todos.forEach()`.

Comment: http://marcmurray.net/toodoo/23-March/index.html Here is a live example of me attempting to implement this forEach method.
It's proving a little tricky in that the class still isn't getting applied, in the top 'card' you can see where I have tried it and the result is blank. ("-item" rather than "2-item" for example)
Is there something I'm missing? 
Thank you by the way!